# Пропало подключение ЛВС из сетевых подключений

Tags: lan, ноутбук

Решено!

Ноутбук ACER ASPIRE 5755G

Разобрал его, поменял термопасту, почистил кулер, после сборки из сетевых подключений пропало подключение ЛВС, осталось только беспроводное сетевое соединение и появилось новое - беспроводное сетевое соединение 2.

Разобрал опять, нашел шлейф, который забыл подключить, подключил, включаюсь, вообще ничего не изменилось! Дрова удалил, поставил снова на LAN, не помогло.

Как исправить?

Решено. Разобрал опять ноутбук, ничего нового там не увидел, все подключено, отключил все, заново подключил, собрал. Включаюсь, появилось...

Comment: В диспетчере устройств всё на месте?

Comment: Да, в этом вся беда, что я понятия не имею, что могло повлиять на пропажу этого соединения.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала выяснить в чем проблема в железе или в Операционной системе. Загрузите для этого какой нибудь дистрибути линукса с флешки - например SLAX.

Comment: Проблема уже решена.